# Filtering data in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible in angularJS to show the data of 2nd pagination page in 1st page while searching ?

Let's say, i have the 50 records of data. Now it's paginated in 5 pages of 10 records per page. Now, I want to display the data in page 1 of 5th page data while filtering.

If it's possible, give me the idea to do that.

```
var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
    if (!needle) {
        return true;
    }
    return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
};

// init the filtered items
$scope.search = function () {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.events, function (event) {
        for(var attr in event) {
            if (searchMatch(event[attr], $scope.query))
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    });
    // take care of the sorting order
    if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
    }
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
};
```

TIA..

Comment: You have to share your current working code.

Comment: @Rahil Actually, now i am showing the data available in corresponding page while searching but my question is i want to display the data of 3rd page in 1st page while user searching in 1st page

Comment: How do you expect us to give you an idea without able to see your code?

Comment: @Rahil updated the code in question

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer below idea.
I have one object named totalObj of 50 records and i am using it to display in DOM using ng-repeat.Now copy that object in orgTotalObj variable. Now when user search by any criteria ,you search in orgTotalObj and update the totalObj variable with this searched item. Now only one element will be displayed in DOM. If user cancel search then you can again assign orgTotalObj to totalObj for displaying all records.

Comment: Can you please tell me with the example ?

Comment: can you share your code on jsfiddle. It will be difficult to give example without seeing the code